# WSO2 IS 5.4: Add a custom ROLE to Service Provider level

Tags: wso2-identity-server

WSO2 IS 5.4: In order to have a custom ROLE to Service Provider level, like ROLE_NAME=AUTH_VALUE and ROLE_VALUES=[SERVICE_1;SERVICE_2], I understand that mechanism could be implemented using Configuring Roles and Permissions for a Service Provider se [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Configuring+Roles+and+Permissions+for+a+Service+Provider) by
Adding Role Mapping button.
Could someone help/explain if that are right and if yes, which value must be entered into the fields "Local Role" and "Service Provider Role"

Any help/ideas is much appreciated, as I'm quite stumped with this.

Answer (score 1):

The document that you have linked explain how you can map internal Identity Server roles (Or roles that Identity Server can access through user stores)  to a custom role that is in the service provider side. For example let's say you have role named "admin" in Identity Server side, but when you send it to the service provider side, you want it to be "owner". So you can do the mapping in this section for "admin" -> "owner" so Identity Server will do the relevant conversions before the claims sent to service provider (Depends on the protocol used to communicate with service provider)

Local role means the role that is in the Identity Server side, according to above example "admin". Service provider role is the role that be used when communicate with the service provider. "owner" according to the above example.